# Having trouble with my $PATH and bash commands

Tags: linux, macos, bash, path, terminal

I keep getting errors saying bash command not found, also I am unable to make changes as it asks for root, even though I am an admin and own the laptop.

I was also able to type .. and move up a directory and now I cannot for some reason.

My second issue is I was formerly able to complete commands in terminal using the  key but now it does not seem to work.

I must add that my $PATH looks very long and muddled at the moment so this may be an issue.

Comment: A handy trick to view your path more comfortably: `tr : '\n' <<<"$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

because your $PATH only contains system admin binary file path, use need to set env like this 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
make sure your local binary file is under dir of /usr/local/bin

Comment: how do I go about that? I have edited text in the .zshrc file in sublime but to no avail and ran rbenv rehash.

Comment: it looks like this export 

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin"

 export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH" # export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

Comment: come to your binary dir and execute the "source" with absolute path.

Comment: how do I do that? 

Apologies for sounding so much like a beginner, I can figure most things out but this is an absolute puzzle today!

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/nano  ~/.bashrc`  **if you are using bash**

Comment: then add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin" export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH" `

Comment: then `/usr/local/bin/source ~/.bashrc`. Your configuration will take effect. then you can use all the command under these PATHS.Try it